# AWS API gateway returns 400 error when square bracket ("[", "]") is in path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I set up API gateway with Lambda Integration and came across this problem.

#### OK case

Request URI: `https://api-gateway-host/stage/hoge`

hoge is not a configured path so this returned:

[OK: missing authentication token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwjpb.png)

#### NG case

Request URI: `https://api-gateway-host/stage/ho[ge`

The path is ho"["ge. It's also not a configured path so I expected same result but:

[NG: 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sgpa.png)

All of `/ho]ge`, `/ho[]ge`, `/ho[g]e`, `/hoge[]` and `/hoge[1]` return the same result.
Actually if square brackets are in "query" like `/hoge?q=hoge[]`, it can be accepted.

Does anyone know the reason? Is it a Api gateway's limitation?
I think it doesn't violate RFC.

Environment

- AWS us-east-1
- Basic setup of Lambda Proxy with empty lambda function
- No request validate (I enabled request validation but the result was same)
- Browser is Google Chrome (same in Curl)

Comment: have you tried url encoding them?

Comment: thank you! url-encoded one can be accepted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, square brackets are not allowed in an API gateway URL. This is a limitation of the service and does *not* align with RFC standards.

- See [this AWS thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=234576) which discusses this limitation in 2016.
- See [this AWS unanswered question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=287209) from just this month (Aug 2018) that again asks when square brackets will be supported.

To get around this limitation, you can encode square brackets, as detailed [in this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=224984).

Comment: Thank you. Both threads discuss "square brackets _in query_" but I tested with it and I couldn't find the limitation, as I described in question: `/hoge?q=hoge[]` can be accepted.` Anyway, url-encoded path parameter can be accepted. We'll workaround with it. Thanks.

Comment: This also applies to curly braces: ?filter={"startDate":{"gte":"2020-02-01"}} requires encoding everything after the =

Comment: The AWS thread referred to has been archived.

Comment: And both threads aren't available on archive.org :(

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with curly braces and as @ninge answer mention it, its a not documented limitation. Pipe and semicolons are listed in the known issues page :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html

However, the RFC on URLs says that they are unsafe characters for this particular reason that gateways might change they way they interpret it.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#page-3