# InvalidQueryStringException on AWS_IAM secured API Gateway Lambda Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I'm passing GET parameters to an AWS API Gateway resource Endpoint ( LAMBDA_PROXY) with serverless.

The GET Parameters are in array annotation, eg. `?filter[someKey]=someValue`, and the parameters are passed to the handler in the event object properly.

As soon as I try to apply an authorizer to that same endpoint (authorizer: AWS_IAM) and use Postman to send the correct Authorization info (AccesKey, SecretKey, SessionToken) with the same GET Request parameters, I'm receiving the following response:
StatusCode: 
`400 Bad Request`
Headers:
`x-amzn-ErrorType InvalidQueryStringException`
Body:
`{"message":null}`

I couldn't find any good info on the InvalidQueryStringException from AWS.

Why are the GET request parameters properly passed to the handler without AWS_IAM authorizer but are rejected with AWS_IAM in place ?

Thank you for an insight on this.

Comment: PS:

Testing the resource endpoint API Gateway via the AWS Console with that same query string yields a correct response...

Comment: Could you just confirm you query string (values are less important than keys)?

Answer (score 1):

Seems, that "percent-encoding" the square brackets is a way to get around the limitation of AWS API Gateway to not support square brackets as part of the query string, which is indeed a little odd.

So just "percent-encoding" the square bracket of the query string: `?filter[someKey]=someValue` to `?filter%5BsomeKey%5D=someValue` did actually help.

Besides, encoding the whole query string part, did not succeed (500, Internal Server Error), so you will very likely end up encoding just the square brackets.

[Stackoverflow: AWS API gateway returns 400 error when square bracket (“[”, “]”) is in path
Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941139/aws-api-gateway-returns-400-error-when-square-bracket-is-in-path/51941567#51941567)